# How to get rid of extra values using eloquent in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am getting extra details like follows while using laravel. Like I want to hide **guarded**, **fillable**, **softdelete**, **appends**, **touches**, **dates**, **visible**, **relations** etc. How can i hide it or just remove it. I just want to display the results in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the toArray() function.

```
User::all()->toArray();

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [email] => 'example@example.com' [password] => 'example' ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [email] => 'example@example.com [password] => 'example ))
```